# Using preg_replace to linkify DOI

Tags: regex, preg-replace, doi

I'm looping through some text with embedded literature references.  Some of these are DOI numbers, and I need to linkify them.

Example text:

```
<div>Interesting article here:  doi:10.1203/00006450-199305000-00005</div>
```

What I've tried so far:

```
$html = preg_replace("\b(10[.][0-9]{4,}(?:[.][0-9]+)*/(?:(?![\"&\'<>])[[:graph:]])+)\b", "<a href='https://doi.org/\\0' target='_new'>doi:\\0</a>",$html);
```

This returns an empty string.

I'm expecting:

```
<div>Interesting article here:  <a href='https://doi.org/10.1203/00006450-199305000-00005' target='_new'>doi:10.1203/00006450-199305000-00005</a></div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

**edit 2018-01-30**: updated DOI resolver per Katrin's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Regular Expression Test Tool](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/) I found an [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10300246/721073) that works for my example text:

```
$pattern        = '(10[.][0-9]{4,}[^\s"/<>]*/[^\s"<>]+)';
$replacement    = "<a href='http://dx.doi.org/$0' target='1'>doi:$0</a>";
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

[CrossRef has a recommendation](https://www.crossref.org/blog/dois-and-matching-regular-expressions/), that they tested successfully on 99.3% of DOIs:

```
/^10.\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$/i
```

Also, the [new recommended resolver resides at `https://doi.org/`](https://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/3_Resolution.html#3.8).

Comment: Thanks, will update my question with the new resolver.

Answer (score 1):

I changed recommended pattern from [CrossRef recommendation pattern](https://www.crossref.org/blog/dois-and-matching-regular-expressions/), then I use this function for my Laravel project:

```
function is_valid_doi($doi)
{
    return preg_match('/^((http(s)?:\/\/)?(dx.)?doi.org\/)?10.\d{4,9}\/[-._;()\/:A-Z\d]+$/i', $doi);
}
```

hope to help you.