# Regex to match DOI in PDF with PyPDF2

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a Python script that extracts DOIs from PDFs, using PyPDF2 and the following regex, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910/finding-a-doi-in-a-document-or-page/10324802#10324802).

```
\b(10[.][0-9]{4,}(?:[.][0-9]+)*/(?:(?!["&\'])\S)+)\b
```

Although this regex works perfectly when I test it against all kinds of DOIs on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tJ6iS8/1), when I use it in the following script, it throws up the error below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding:utf-8 -*-

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import re
import sys

pdf_file = sys.argv[1]
doi_re = re.compile("\b(10[.][0-9]{4,}(?:[.][0-9]+)*/(?:(?!["&\'])\S)+)\b")
input = PdfFileReader(file(pdf_file, "rb"))
text = input.getPage(0).extractText()

m = doi_re.search(text)
print(m.group(0))
```

```
File "/Users/fort/Documents/Dropbox/Code/Python/pdf2doi/pdf2doi.py", line 9
doi_re = re.compile("\b(10[.][0-9]{4,}(?:[.][0-9]+)*/(?:(?!["&\'])\S)+)\b")
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

My editor's syntax highlighting suggests that the parser doesn't like `'])\S)+)\b")`, so I tried escaping the double quotes preceding it, which gets rid of that particular problem, i.e.,

```
\b(10[.][0-9]{4,}(?:[.][0-9]+)*/(?:(?![\"&\'])\S)+)\b
```

However, the regex no longer matches DOIs. (Enclosing the regex in single quotes also fixes this syntax error, but with the same outcome.)

Finally, the script does match some DOIs if I use the following regex instead, but it misses quite a few:

```
10.(\d)+/([^(\s\>\"\<)])+
```

Any ideas on how to get this working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have an earlier " that you should escape. In

```
["&\']
```

If that is not working, please fix the regex101 reference that just points to a general page.

Filling the regex and some samples could help us further fix the problem.

Comment: Here's the [direct link to the regex101 page](http://regex101.com/r/tJ6iS8/1), with the regex matching a very complex, fake, but valid DOI.

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, escaping the `"` breaks the regex, i.e., it fails to match DOIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `"` in a `"` quoted string unless you use `\"` to transfer it.

Or you can use three double-quotes: `"""\b(10[.][0-9]{4,}(?:[.][0-9]+)*/(?:(?!["&\'])\S)+)\b"""`

Comment: Unfortunately, that still fails to match DOIs when I use it the script, and throws up the following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @fort It means `m` is `None` and `text` does not match the pattern.

Comment: Yes, but that only happens if I escape the `"` which causes the problem in the script. However, the regex itself is, according to regex101, a valid Python-flavoured regex, and it matches all DOIs. If I use the last regex in my OP instead, the script extracts (some) DOIs correctly.