# Whats the correct format of Java String REGEX to identify DOI

Tags: java, regex, doi

I am conducting some research on identify DOI in free format text.

I am using Java 8 and REGEX

I Have [found](https://www.crossref.org/blog/dois-and-matching-regular-expressions/) these REGEX's that are supposed to fulfil my requirements

```
/^10.\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$/i
/^10.1002/[^\s]+$/i
/^10.\d{4}/\d+-\d+X?(\d+)\d+<[\d\w]+:[\d\w]*>\d+.\d+.\w+;\d$/i
/^10.1021/\w\w\d++$/i
/^10.1207/[\w\d]+\&\d+_\d+$/i
```

The code I am trying is

```
private static final Pattern pattern_one = Pattern.compile("/^10.\\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$/i", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern_one.matcher("http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/JPO3002.1");
while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
                System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

However the matcher doesnt find anything.

Where have I gone wrong?

UPDATE

I have encountered a valid DOI that my set of REGEXs do not match

heres an example DOI : `10.1175/1520-0485(2002)032<0870:CT>2.0.CO;2`

Why doesn't this pattern work?

```
/^10.\d{4}/\d+-\d+X?(\d+)\d+<[\d\w]+:[\d\w]*>\d+.\d+.\w+;\d$/i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, a regex is written as a String. In other languages, the regex is quoted using `/.../`, with options like `i` given after the ending `/`. So, what is written as `/XXX/i` will in Java be done like this:

```
// Using flags parameter
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("XXX", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

// Using embedded flags
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)XXX");
```

In most languages, regex are using to *find* a matching substring. Java can do that too, using the [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) method (or any of the many `replaceXxx()` regex methods), however Java also has the [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) method which will match against the entire string, eliminating the need for the begin and end boundary matchers `^` and `$`.

Anyway, your problem is that the regex has both `^` and `$` boundary matchers, which means it will only work if string is nothing but the text you want to match. Since you actually want to *find* a substring, remove those matchers.

To search for one of multiple patterns, using the `|` logical regex operator.

And finally, since Java regex is given as a String literal, any special characters, most notably `\`, needs to be escaped.

So, to build a single regex that can *find* substrings matching any of the following:

```
/^10.\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$/i
/^10.1002/[^\s]+$/i
/^10.\d{4}/\d+-\d+X?(\d+)\d+<[\d\w]+:[\d\w]*>\d+.\d+.\w+;\d$/i
/^10.1021/\w\w\d++$/i
/^10.1207/[\w\d]+\&\d+_\d+$/i
```

You would write it like this:

```
String regex = "10.\\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+" +
              "|10.1002/[^\\s]+" +
              "|10.\\d{4}/\\d+-\\d+X?(\\d+)\\d+<[\\d\\w]+:[\\d\\w]*>\\d+.\\d+.\\w+;\\d" +
              "|10.1021/\\w\\w\\d++" +
              "|10.1207/[\\w\\d]+\\&\\d+_\\d+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

String input = "http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/JPO3002.1";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Start index: " + m.start() +
                       " End index: " + m.end() +
                       " " + m.group());
}
```

*Output*

```
Start index: 37 End index: 54 10.1175/JPO3002.1
```

Comment: Really nice work. Thanks very much for taking the time to fully explain where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern looks incorrect to me.  You are currently using this:

```
/^10.\\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$/i
```

But I think you intend to use this:

```
^.*/10\\.\\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$
```

Problems with your pattern include that you are using JavaScript regex syntax, or some other language's syntax.  Also, you were not escaping a literal dot in the regex, and the start of the pattern marker was out of place.

**Code:**

```
String pattern = "^.*/10\\.\\d{4,9}/[-._;()/:A-Z0-9]+$";
String url = "http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/JPO3002.1";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(url);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester